# SVG is supposed to use its own color regardless css fill: currentColor

Tags: css, svg, sass

my problem is this:

```
.icon {
  color: red;

  > svg {
    fill: currentColor;

    path,
    use {
      fill: currentColor;
    }
  }
}
```

now i need to overwrite the code above with css/sass again and tell to the svg that it should use his own  fill value:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" **fill="#e1306c"**>
```

I cnt solve this - please help!

Comment: Just wrap it in a div so the >svg {...} css doesn't override it. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: instead of using a `fill` attribute use `style:color:...`